# javascript: How to abort $.post()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have the post method as shown below:

```
$(".buttons").click(function(){
  var gettopic=$.post("topic.php", {id: topicId}, function(result){
  // codes for handling returned result

  });
})
```

I tried to abort the old post when a new button is clicked:
So I tired

```
$(".buttons").click(function(){
    if (gettopic) {
        gettopic.abort();
    }
    var gettopic=$.post("topic.php", {id: topicId}, function(result){
         // codes for handling returned result
    });
})
```

However this is not working. So I wondered how this could be fixed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [abort AJAX post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7565798/abort-ajax-post)

Answer (score 11):

You have to define  your variable `gettopic` outside the `click` event

```
var gettopic;
$(".buttons").click(function(){
    if (gettopic)
    {
    gettopic.abort();
    }
    gettopic=$.post("topic.php", {id: topicId}, function(result){
               // codes for handling returned result
    });
})
```

Comment: Priceless!! This is great solution to use abort()!

Answer (score 1):

```
var xhr = [];

$('.methods a').click(function(){
    var target = $(this).attr('href');

    //if user clicks fb_method buttons
    if($(this).hasClass('fb_method')){
        //do ajax request (add the post handle to the xhr array)
        xhr.push( $.post("/ajax/get_fb_albums.php", function(msg) {                           
            $(target).html('').append(msg).fadeIn();
        }) );
    } else {
        //abort ALL ajax request
        for ( var x = 0; x < xhr.length; x++ )
        {
            xhr[x].abort();
        }
        $(target).fadeIn();
    }
    return false;
});
```

Using jquery you can use in this way:

```
var xhr = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "some.php",
    data: "name=John&location=Boston",
    success: function(msg){
        alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
    }
});

//kill the request
xhr.abort()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use this code

$.post.abort();

Comment: answer is not clear and if possible, provide sufficient supporting information or codes

Answer (score -1):

A post request, depending on server and client bandwidth&latency, can happen in less than 20ms. Windows default double-click time is 500 ms, so no, you can't and shouldn't expect to be able to abort it.